# Get a Twitter feed to my website using PHP

Tags: php, html, twitter

I was just wondering, what PHP methods would I use to get the most recent tweet of a twitter user to display in a box on my website?

any suggestions on how i may achieve this would be great.

cheers

Comment: Have you tried googling this? Because the answer is found in the first result of the google search for "`twitter feed to website`". No PHP needed either. And just to make it a little easier for you: http://www.google.com/search?q=twitter+feed+to+website

Comment: Yes, that is why in the question, I wondered if there was a way to do it using PHP!

Comment: See http://apiwiki.twitter.com/

Comment: There is. Twitter has an API and RSS feeds as well, but it would be more hassle. I haven't used the API, but I have done PHP RSS parsing, and while it's not hard, copying and pasting a JS snippet is much, much easier.

Comment: but when someone asks for something in PHP why would they settle for javascript? ;)

Comment: Because with a PHP call you have to worry about things like running into the API call limit, and then either having to add caching to your PHP function, or else risk the rest of the page dying. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060876/why-is-this-twitter-api-script-failing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is also a built in simplexml function:

```
// Parse the raw xml
$xml    =    simplexml_load_file('http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/{yourfeed}.rss');


// Go through each tweet
foreach ($xml->channel->item as $tweet)
{
    echo $tweet->title . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: put that in your website and you will block your servers sockets and eventually get blocked by twitter, your website will bei significantly slower and you have an external uncontrollable error source that can kill your whole site.

- do error handling, cache the results, think of some logic when and how to fetch. through a user hitting the website is possible but a very bad idea. cronjob? 
if you fetch it on page generation use some sort of locking to ensure only one request is fetching data and storing it for other requests

Comment: This is purely an example. Of course it needs caching, error handling, a timeout, html escaping, parsing for urls and much more. This was a simple answer, to his simple question. He asked "any suggestions" this is a suggestion, not the EXACT/FULL solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try a library:
http://dev.twitter.com/pages/libraries#php

Or, if those seem like overkill for some reason, load the feed via cURL and simplexml_load_string.  Manipulate as needed.

This will show your last tweet:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init("http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/{yourtwitterfeed}.rss");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

$data = simplexml_load_string(curl_exec($ch));
curl_close($ch);

echo $data->channel->item[0]->title;
```

**EDIT** : Ha.  Or you can use simplexml_load_file("{url goes here}") instead of all that cURL stuff. I forgot you can do that.

Comment: Wow, Brilliant thankyou. never seen that curl library of functions before. thats awesome to know. However i wondered if there was way to do this without installing the curl library. 

Alternatively, how do i install this library?

Comment: If your version of PHP doesn't have cURL setup, there are instructions here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.setup.php

Depending on your setup and experience this can be a bit of a pain.

Client-side solutions for Twitter are probably better if all you want to do is a display a single tweet or two from a specific user.  I'd look at the link user356981 supplied below, Twitter's own profile widget  (http://twitter.com/goodies/widget_profile) or jTweetsAnywhere (http://thomasbillenstein.com/jTweetsAnywhere/).